Не подключается к веб-интерфейсу celery flower
Запускаю в своем проекте celery worker следующим образом:
celery -A celery_app:celery_app worker -P threads

далее запускаю flower следующим образом:
celery -A celery_app:celery_app flower

Получаю стандартный вывод:
[I 240601 16:26:27 command:168] Visit me at http://0.0.0.0:5555
[I 240601 16:26:27 command:176] Broker: redis://localhost:6379//
[I 240601 16:26:27 command:177] Registered tasks: 
    ['celery.accumulate',
     'celery.backend_cleanup',
     'celery.chain',
     'celery.chord',
     'celery.chord_unlock',
     'celery.chunks',
     'celery.group',
     'celery.map',
     'celery.starmap',
     'tasks.modify_picture.create_picture']
[I 240601 16:26:27 mixins:228] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//

Но при попытке подключиться по localhost:5555 получаю бесконечную загрузку, в чем может быть проблема?
